# Load entity by id with SINGLE_TABLE inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance

I use `Hibernate` v.4 (inside `Spring MVC`). There are several inherited entities mapped on one table with `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy using `DiscriminatorColumn`:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
public class B extends A {
   ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "C")
public class C extends A {
   ...
}
```

Consider I have universal GUI interface for managing this entities, so in input (say in `HttpServletRequest`) I have only **`id`** of the object, but I don't know which type exactly is this object; that is why I can not specify exact class for `session.load(...)`. But for specific parts I need access to specific fields of entities, so I have to cast object to precise type (`B` or `C`).

So, when I'm doing  `A a = (A) session.load(A.class, id);` it constructs proxy object under type `A`, so it can not be cast to `B` or `C`:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: my.A_$$_jvst551_6 cannot be cast to my.B`

The question: is any way how I can configure my entities or use special tricks to load entity from database and obtain object of precise type of which correspondence row presents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's easy: I should use `session.get(A.class, id)` instead of `session.load(...)`.